# Angular 8: Upload file

Tags: angular, httpclient

I'm using the following angular code in order to upload a file to the server. 
I wrote the server, so I can see all data sent from client.

```js
let file=fileList[0];
let body: FormData = new FormData();
body.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
this.http.post ('http://localhost:8000',body).subscribe(
(val) => 
    {
        console.log("GET call successful value returned in body");
        //this.OpenScenario (val);
    },
    response => {
        console.log("GET call in error", response);
    },
    () => {
        console.log("The GET observable is now completed.");
    });
```

The server is getting a message, but without the file body. 
Can you please tell what is wrong in my code ?

Thank you in advance,
Zvika

Comment: Are you using an proxy.config.json

Comment: Can you provide server-side code?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code might be you need to check with postman if it is working or not?

Comment: Thank you all. My server is just a TCP socket that received a message and parse it.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample proxy.config.json ?  The client (under chrome) is trying to send a put request with a body. The server runs on the same PC. Thank you in advance.